# python does not create json files from crontab

Tags: python, json, cron

I have a python file that creates json files from database, when I run it from the terminal (python pythonfile.py) it works without problems, but when I create a crontab that executes that python every 2 minutes, it does not create the files, the crontab runs the python without problems, I know because before creating the files json makes a change in the database and I can see that change in the database, what will be the problem?

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi  pi 5721 nov 15 02:36 searchProgramData.py

@reboot python /home/pi/aufen/searchProgramData.py >> /tmp/log.txt
*/2 * * * * python /home/pi/aufen/searchProgramData.py >> /tmp/log.txt

query = "SELECT * FROM det_programacion where programacion_id = %s "%programacion_grupo[0][2]
            detalles_programacion = run_query(query)
            json_str = json.dumps(detalles_programacion,default=datetime_handler)
            #escribir json de array
            with open('datos.json', 'w') as file:
                json.dump(json_str, file)
```

Comment: try to specify an absolute path for your json file.

Comment: Does your cronjob have enough privileges to run the script?